# Does cascading LUTs work to reduce logic resources in an FPGA?

Tags: digital-logic, fpga

I have seen suggestions where a cascade of two LUTs can implement larger LUT functions with fewer SRAM bits, but I have not seen any mathematical proof or logical argument that it works.

For example, to get 6 inputs (LUT6) simply cascade a LUT4 to a LUT4 and now you have 6 (or 7) inputs. Is this approach valid?

On the face of it I would say no, seems obvious, but I'm not sure how to prove or disprove this with a logical or mathematical argument. Any ideas?

Perhaps the cascade is a valid tradeoff of speed vs. resources, but I need to be able to prove this conclusively one way or the other.

[image: LUT4 cascade]

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to figure it out by yourself, so here's a hint: How many possible states can the 6 input signals be in? How many bits do you need to store the output value for each of them? 4 inputs have 16 states so that a LUT4 needs exactly 16 bit of memory to decode them all.

Comment: Whether or not it's valid may depend on your performance goals. Four of your inputs will be slower than the others.

Comment: you think you have 6 inputs but notice that the first 4 have to boil down to 1 bit and then that 1 bit has to combine with the other 2. It's not the same as a real 6-input LUT. However, many FPGAs allow you to combine two 5-input LUTs to make a 6-input LUT, and they operate in parallel not series, with a muxer at the output.

Answer (score 3):

"LUT" stands for "look-up table".  Which means that each LUT is a teeny bit of RAM.  A 4-in, 1-out LUT can chose any arbitrary binary function from the 16 possible input combinations to the one possible output combination.

A 7-in, 1-out LUT would choose any arbitrary function from 128 possible input combinations.

The cascade that you show only has 32 RAM bits, so of necessity it could only map at most 32 unique input combinations (out of 128 possible) to the one output.

If the 7-input, 1-output logic function that you want to implement *happens* to be one that will work with that configuration, then, yes, it will reduce the number of LUTs needed.  If you had a function that you needed to implement that did not match that architecture, then you'd need to use more LUTs.

A big part of the reason we use logic synthesis is that we can just tell the synthesizer what we want, and let it deal with figuring out how to minimize such paths.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that approach is valid (and this is how synthesis does it), but \$f_{max}\$ for a clock is defined by the longest combinatorial path (i.e. chain of LUTs) between two flip-flops using that clock.